# Can a transient variable be serialized in any way?

Tags: java

I faced this question in an interview. Please help me to find the answer. The question was Can a transient variable be serialized in any way?

Comment: by implementing own [`readObject()`/`writeObject()`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`static` and `transient` fields are not serialized by default.

However they can be serialized if

- the same object is accessible via a serialized field.
- the object is serialized in a readObject/writeObject or readExternalizable/writeExternalizable.
- you are using a different serialization library with different rules (I don't know any which serializes `static` fields, though I have written such a library by mistake once)

Usually a field is made `transient` to mean it shouldn't be serialized, though sometimes it might be because

- the type is not `Serializable`
- you don't want to use the default Serialization.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Somewhere I read that it can be serialized using  encryption. Do you have any idea on this.

Comment: @RoyalTiger encryption is something you do only after an object has been serialized to a stream of bytes making it too late to add any information.

Answer (score 1):

Recently in an interview I was also asked this question and here what I answered

Yes, transient member can be serialized. We need to do following to acheive same:

- Make your non-serialisable field transient
- In writeObject(), first call defaultWriteObject() on the stream to
  store all the non-transient fields, then call other methods to
  serialize the individual properties of your non-serializable object.
- In readObject(), first call defaultReadObject() on the stream to read
  back all the non-transient fields, then call other methods
  (corresponding to the ones you added to writeObject) to deserialise
  your non-serializable object.